# Video isn't loaded only in Safari. How can I fix it?

Tags: video, safari, next.js, mp4, webm

I've Next.js [web app](https://webnos.online/all) and use videos (webm and mp4). All works fine, but videos aren't loaded (without any errors) exactly in Safari (Chrome works very well), but when I clear a cache videos start to work for a while.

Pice of code with video on my page:

```
<>
  <Wrap background={background}>
    <StyledVideo autoPlay muted loop>
      <source src={videoProps.src} type='video/webm' />
    </StyledVideo>
  </Wrap>
</>
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Is your only source on the tag a webm? Try and add fallbacks, support is partial https://caniuse.com/webm

Comment: I also use mp4 format for another video, but the problem is the same. I'll try fallback for webm one.

Comment: One more detail is that in dev mode (localhost) all works well even in Safari.